# Orientation change with activity that download from internet. Android

Tags: android, twitter, screen-orientation, android-orientation, screen-rotation

Im developing an app that download tweets from twitter.
When my app change orientation, the activity loads again the tweets (it downloads again the same tweets).
So whats the best solution for a case like this ?
Is using android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" a way to go ? I have read that is a bad practice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to avoid downloading same tweets again.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(<Key>, <Value>);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When the orientation is changed, restore the saved tweets.

**[Edit]**
Alternatively, you can do it without overriding `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState!= null) {
    value = savedInstanceState.getSerializable(<Key>);
  }
}
```

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, if for example, i have 3 tweets i should do:

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(<Key1>, <Tweet1>);
savedInstanceState.putSerializable(<Key2>, <Tweet2>);
savedInstanceState.putSerializable(<Key3>, <Tweet3>);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

Comment: This will be an overhead if you want to increase the number of tweets to display. I would suggest some ArrayList for it.